# How to omit adding '\n' (newline char) to a char array reading from file

Tags: java, file-io, newline, arrays

I apologize if this question has been asked before. I searched for it and did not seem to be able to find a solution...

I am adding chars to a char[] from a .txt file.

I want to add all chars to the array *except* new-line chars ('\n'?).

This is what I am trying, which is not working.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StateReader extends FilterInputStream
{
    private static final int FIELD_SIZE = 25 * 25;
    static int readCount = 0;
    private DataInputStream ds; 

    public StateReader(InputStream in)
    {
       super(in);
       ds = new DataInputStream(in);
    }

    public char[] readState() throws IOException
    {
          char current;
          char[] stateChar = new char[FIELD_SIZE];
          int index = 0;

          while (index < stateChar.length) 
          {
             current = (char) ds.read();

             if(current == '\n')
             {
                current = (char) ds.read();    // Attempting to read char after
                stateChar[index++] = current;  // '\n' encountered, and store that.
             } else {
                stateChar[index++] = current;  // Stores whatever is read.
             }
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < stateChar.length; i++)
          {
             System.out.printf("" + stateChar[i]);  // Prints out contents of Array
                                                    // For troubleshooting...
          }

          return stateChar;
       }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a (better) way to do this.

As stated before, I'm trying to copy the contents of the text file to a char[], excluding new-line characters.

I am then basing a switch on the contents of this array and populating stuff accordingly. The problem is when the switch encounters a new-line character it doesn't know what to do. I tried adding a case for '\n' which recursively calls the same function... Needless to say, it didn't work.
(This '\n' case was tried without the 'if' statement in the readState() method).

```
public State findState(int p, Cell c)
{
   State myState = null;
   switch (charStateList[p])
   {
      case 'x':   System.out.println("Read 'x':"+readCount);
                  readCount++;
                  myState = new Wall(c);
                  break;
      case 'o':   System.out.println("Read 'o':"+readCount);
                  readCount++;
                  myState = new Empty(c);
                  break;
      case '\n':  findState(p, c);
                  break;
      default:    System.out.println("Default:" + readCount);
                  readCount++;
                  myState = new Empty(c);
                  break;
   }

   return myState;
}
```

I tried .equals(), but won't work for a char.

Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated. And again, my apologize if this has been answered already.

Edit: Is there a way I can simply set a delimiter for the FileInputStream/DataInputStream, so that it is ignored?

Comment: What type is `ds`? I was going to suggest using the `readline` method for stream text line reading, which gives you the text lines without the line terminators, but your second version of `readState` confuses me as it seems to be totally different in functionality from your first version. So it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I'm doing is populating an board-grid with different states. The purpose of the .txt file is to make a 'map'. It's easiest if I can start new lines, so I can have a visual of the layout.
What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the chars in the .txt file, then populate then set the cells of the board with different 'states'.
'ds' is a DataInputStream.
Edit: I'll add the whole class. It's not much extra.

Comment: For clarification I renamed the second readState(), as it isn't meant for the same thing, and is in different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your file was structured. But here is a code that make adding chars to a char[] from a .txt file more easier:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TxtToChar {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "";
        char[] c;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                string += scanner.useDelimiter("\n").nextLine();

            }
             c = string.toCharArray();
             for(int i =0;i<c.length;i++){
                             if(c[i] !=' '){
                               System.out.println(c[i]);
                             }
             }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was just thinking about how it would be better to add each line to a string, then convert to a a char array.
Certain this will solve my problem!
Cheers, and happy Easter!

Answer (score 0):

Use [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). The default delimiter is white-space.